# Configuration qualifiers for 320x480 Android (Galaxy Ace)

Tags: java, android, dpi, screen-size

I have an application that I am struggling to make look right on a Galaxy Ace 320*480 mdpi.

Using drawable-sw320dp-mdpi seems to effect most of the other screens such as the Galaxy S2 (480*800 hpdi) even though I have a drawable-sw480dp etc which should be used automatically on higher res?

Really confused with this, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is if it's not showing up right on the Ace, that it's identifying itself as a different screen size/density than you think it should be. My guess is that it's actually a lower density than you think, but without some kind of screen shots or further description on what you're seeing I don't know anyone can offer much more help.

Answer (score 0):

//you need to run this in API level 13 OS version 3.2 and above.

for the < 3.2 you need to declare normal `drawable-mdpi`

as your samsung ACE OS version might be 2.2.1